# Gas wall Heating

Tags: walls, heating, gas

I have a gas wall heater that only heats one side.it is ductless & forced air out of the one side.  How do (or can) I convert it so that it heats both? Or possibly a vent kit that divert heat to ductwork then into the back bedrooms? Laying out the vent’s & ductwork is simple matter but how would I catch that hot air to flow up & thru ducts? I am a renter so option of replacing heating system is out. I am paying exactly $100 more a month than I was for same months last year. Any ideas? Attached is picture of similar model in my wall [image]

Comment: Make/model of the heater and maybe some pics would be helpful. I'm not an HVAC guy, so I'm not clear on whether this is a heater for the wall, if it's a room heater that mounts on the wall, is it directly piped with gas and there's a burner inside the device or does it get hot air/water from somewhere else to release the heat into the room. [Edit]ing some more details would definitely help.

Comment: It’s gas piped in standard wall heater it’s a Williams model . If it was a heater that mounted to wall I would have said as such it’s a basic gas wall heater with thermostat that turns it on or off gas pipes with pilot light. Don’t know model # just hoping that there is some type of diverter kit that’ll keep the family warm in d upload a photo but haven’t figured that you it in this site only second time on thank you